# jsTree customize <li> using the alternative JSON format along with AJAX

Tags: jstree

I am using the alternative JSON format along with AJAX to load data in tree. Now there is a new ask, I am required to add a new element at the end of <li> tag.

I have created sample URL to display what I am currently doing.
[Tree crated using alternative JSON format along with AJAX](http://secure.chiwater.com/CodeSample/)

[image]

And how the new LI should appear
[Tree created using hard coded HTML but shows how the LI should look like](http://secure.chiwater.com/CodeSample/Home/CreateTreeFromHtml)

[image: Expected icon next to tree node]

I think I should be able to do this if I use HTML Data but since the project is already live with JSON format this would require me to change a lot so before I start making this major change I just wanted to check if this is possible using JSON and AJAX format or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got answer from Ivan - [Answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jstree/W7_q-SPL01A)

In short there is misc.js in the src folder which has question mark plugin, this is the best example of what I wanted to do.

I tweaked its code for my needs and here is the new code.

```
(function ($, undefined) {
    "use strict";
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.className = 'glyphicons glyphicons-comments flip jstree-comment'

    $.jstree.defaults.commenticon = $.noop;
    $.jstree.plugins.commenticon = function (options, parent) {
        this.bind = function () {
            parent.bind.call(this);            
        };
        this.teardown = function () {
            if (this.settings.commenticon) {
                this.element.find(".jstree-comment").remove();
            }
            parent.teardown.call(this);
        };
        this.redraw_node = function (obj, deep, callback, force_draw) {
            var addCommentIcon = true;
            var data = this.get_node(obj).data;
            //....Code for deciding whether comment icon is needed or not based on "data"
            var li = parent.redraw_node.call(this, obj, deep, callback, force_draw);
            if (li && addCommentIcon) {
                var tmp = span.cloneNode(true);
                tmp.id = li.id + "_commenticon";
                var $a = $("a", li);
                $a.append(tmp);
            }
            return li;
        };
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this add only the parent nodes ? What if we want t add the child nodes as well ?

Comment: @YashSaraiya - This will work for both parent nodes as well as child nodes.